# Check specific lengths of subdomain in htaccess with regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to filter a 2 tier level subdomain to my website.

The form is as follows:

[country].[category].mywebsite.com ~ where country is 2 characters.

I'm trying to have a rewrite rule for 3 permutations:

```
-[country].[category].mywebsite.com = mywebsite.com?country=%1&category=%2
-[category].mywebsite.com = mywebsite.com?category=%1
-[country].mywebsite.com = mywebsite.com?country=%1
```

The following is what i have currently.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mywebsite.com$ [NC] # Presuming you don't want to do www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.mywebsite\.com [NC] # Catch subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?country=%1&category_subs=%2 [QSA,L]
```

I'm not sure if there is any way to filter regex by the lengths so that i can filter all 2 characters subdomains out from country.

Any help or advise greatly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These may get you started (add flags and additional conditions as needed):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w\w)\.(\w+)\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?country=%1&category=%2

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w\w)\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?country=%1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.mywebsite\.com [NC] # Note: this will also rewrite the country URL if you don't [END] there
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?category=%1
```

Comment: not working on my side. The first rule is out already. print_r($_GET) returning empty array.